# Including relationships in eloquent resource collection optionally

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-eloquent-resource

I want load relationship optionally on collection api end point

The end point will be something like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/?include=comments includes comments with posts and I can add more using comma, like

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/?include=comments,images
```

but when I am not passing these query parameter, it should only return `posts` with end point `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts?page=10`

**RequestQueryFilter**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class RequestQueryFilter
{
    public function attach($resource, Request $request = null)
    {
        $request = $request ?? request();
        return tap($resource, function($resource) use($request) {
            $this->getRequestIncludes($request)->each(function($include) use($resource) {
                $resource->load($include);
            });
        });
    }
    protected function getRequestIncludes(Request $request)
    {
        // return collect(data_get($request->input(), 'include', [])); //single relationship
        return collect(array_map('trim', explode(',', data_get($request->input(), 'include', [])))); //multiple relationships
    }
}
```

in **Helper**

```
<?php
if ( ! function_exists('filter') ) {
    function filter($attach) 
    {
        return app('filter')->attach($attach);
    }
}
?>
```

In **PostController**

```
public funciton index(Request $request) {
    $posts = Post::all();
    return new PostCollection(filter($posts));
}
```

In **PostCollection**

```
return [
            'data' => $this->collection->transform(function($post){
                return [
                    'id' => $post->id,
                    'title' => $post->title,
                    'body' => $post->body,
                    'comments' =>  new CommentCollection($post->whenLoaded('comments')),
                     'images' =>  new ImageCollection($post->whenLoaded('images'))
                ];
            }),
        ];
```

Showing

> Call to undefined method App\Models\Post::whenLoaded()",
>   but in if I am using single model resource, it is working fine.

**Update:**
Cause:- post collection transform gives

```
 Collection gives 
 Post {#363
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "id"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "posts"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:9 [
```

but Post resource `$this` gives

```
Post {#344
  +resource: Post {#343
    #guarded: array:1 [
      0 => "id"
    ]
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: "posts"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:9 [
```

now converting PostCollection $post to PostResource

```
 'data' => $this->collection->transform(function($post) use ($request) {
    $post = new PostResource($post);
    dd($post);
```

Using this

`'comments' =>  new CommentCollection($post->whenLoaded('comments')),` will always return comments, even there is no `comments` in `include`

```
$post->relationLoaded('comments')
```

returns true always.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is by design or a bug. My best guess is that it doesn't work with collections because `whenLoaded($relation)` is a method of the resource class, not the model itself. But as a workaround, the following should work:

```
return [
    'data' => $this->collection->transform(function ($post) {
        return [
           'id' => $post->id,
           'title' => $post->title,
           'body' => $post->body,
           'comments' => $this->when($post->relationLoaded('comments'), function () use ($post) {
              return new CommentCollection($post->comments);
           }),
           'images' => $this->when($post->relationLoaded('images'), function () use ($post) {
              return new ImageCollection($post->images);
           })
        ];
    }),
];
```

---

As you are always getting `true` returned by `$post->relationLoaded('comments')`, my suggestion is create a new method on your base model (or if you don't have one, the `Post` model) which not only checks for the loading state but also contents of the relation:

```
public function relationLoadedAndNotEmpty(string $relation): bool
{
    return $this->relationLoaded($relation) && 
           $this->getRelation($relation) instanceof \Illuminate\Support\Collection &&
           $this->getRelation($relation)->isNotEmpty();
}
```

Using this method in the resource as suggested above instead of ´$post->relationLoaded('comments')` should give you the desired results as it will also avoid printing the attribute if the collection is empty.

Comment: I have already tried that, it will return relationships independent of query parameters.

Comment: That sounds odd. The relation shouldn't be loaded according to your code. Do you use `protected $with = ['comments', 'images']` in your `Post` model by any chance?

Comment: By the way, you should filter the relations which are allowed to be loaded... Add some sort of whitelist.

Comment: Agree with you, but that is independent of this question.

Comment: That's why it's an extra comment besides my other question. :)

Comment: For your comment “That sounds odd...” no I have not.

Comment: I have updated my question with some new observation, can you please take a look, may be you can suggest something.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I updated my answer with a second suggestion.

Comment: Just tried, but no different result, but customizing it a little bit may give the desire result, I feel so.